# jsonPath - how to filter results by matching substring

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonpath

I have a structure like this:

```
{"payload": {

    "Item1": {
      "property1": "Sunday",
      "property2": "suffering_8890"
    },

    "Item2": {
      "property1": "Monday",
      "property2": "misery_0776"
    },

    "Item3": {
      "property1": "Tuesday",
      "property2": "pain_6756"
    }
  }
}
```

I need the property2 value that contains a certain sub-string (i.e- "misery"). Ultimately I just need the 4-digit code, but even getting the full value will work. I am able to get a list of all the property2 values by using:

```
$..property2
```

This returns:

```
Result[0] = suffering_8890
Result[1] = misery_0776
Result[2] = pain_6756
```

How do I filter it so that it only gives me the result containing the substring "misery"?

Comment: Do you need `4-digit code` which in this case `0776` or `misery`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With regards to full value you can use a [Filter Operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators) like:

```
$..[?(@.property2 =~ /misery.*?/i)].property2
```

Demo:

[image]

You can extract the 4-digit value out of the variable using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

---

If you want to do this in one shot:

1. Add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the request which returns above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   vars.put('misery', ((com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), '$..[?(@.property2 =~ /misery.*?/i)].property2').get(0) =~ ('(\\d+)'))[0][1]))
   ```
3. Refer the extracted value as `${misery}` where required

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: This worked. Thanks for putting in the effort to show how it can be done in one step!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [regular expression extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as well for the mentioned scenario to fetch the four-digit as below

```
property2": "misery_(.*)"
```

This will help you to save the four-digit code in JMeter variables right away. If you insist you to find out the required value from JSON using [jsonpath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2), you can use JSON filter as below :-

```
$..[?(@.property2.indexOf('misery')>=0)]..property2
```

Comment: I tried regex initially, but it didn't work. The Jmeter built-in regex tester can't find a match. But any online regex extractor is able to evaluate the expression and find the match. 

The second solution throws the Exception: Arguments to function: 'indexOf' are not closed properly.